# silverlight 4 datagrid center column header

Tags: datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I am unable to center a column header in silverlight 4.

this is my static resource:

```
<my:CAddTransaction.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="CenterHeaderText" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
 </my:CAddTransaction.Resources>
```

this is the column:

```
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Include?" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterHeaderText}" >
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                   <CheckBox Name="bInclude" IsChecked="{Binding bInclude, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
             </DataTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

the result is the column header is left justified.

Comment: I think it is centered, just offset a bit due to some padding on the right.  Not sure how you fix that ...

Comment: Check if it still showing 'Sort Icon' :)

Comment: @dbaseman.. I think your right.  There does appear to be something going on on the right side of the header.  I put a few spaces in the front of the Header text and before the text got all the way to the right side of the cell, the text started to disappear.  If anyone knows how to get rid of that I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Login}" Header="My Column Title" Width="100">
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
         <Style TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
             <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
         </Style>
    </controls:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stil need help, this works fine for me. Also when user changes column width.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn> 
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle> 
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader"> 
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/> 
        </Style> 
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle> 
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```